# Javascript: Convert ondeviceReady function to click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that runs on device ready:

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    },

    onDeviceReady: function() {
        var div = document.querySelector('.app');
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Scanning...'));
        div.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

        // scan for any BLE devices for 10 seconds
        ble.scan([], 10, app.onDeviceDiscovered);

        setTimeout(app.scanComplete, 10500);
    },

    onDeviceDiscovered: function(peripheral) {
        // print peripheral details to the the console and the UI
        var peripheralString = JSON.stringify(peripheral, null, 2);
        console.log(peripheralString);

        var div = document.querySelector('.app');
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Found Device'));
        var pre = document.createElement('pre');
        pre.innerText = peripheralString;
        div.appendChild(pre);
    },

    scanComplete: function() {
        // update the UI indicating the scan is complete
        var div = document.querySelector('.app');
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Scan complete.'));
    }    

};

app.initialize();
```

What I need to do is to run the above code only if a button is clicked and NOT on device ready.

Something like this:

```
    $(document).on('click', ".letmepairBtn", function(){

var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    },
  onDeviceReady: function() {
        var div = document.querySelector('.app');
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Scanning...'));
        div.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

        // scan for any BLE devices for 10 seconds
        ble.scan([], 10, app.onDeviceDiscovered);

        setTimeout(app.scanComplete, 10500);
    },

    onDeviceDiscovered: function(peripheral) {
        // print peripheral details to the the console and the UI
        var peripheralString = JSON.stringify(peripheral, null, 2);
        console.log(peripheralString);

        var div = document.querySelector('.app');
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Found Device'));
        var pre = document.createElement('pre');
        pre.innerText = peripheralString;
        div.appendChild(pre);
    },

    scanComplete: function() {
        // update the UI indicating the scan is complete
        var div = document.querySelector('.app');
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Scan complete.'));
    }    

};

app.initialize();  

    });
```

But when I run my code, the code fails to work. The reason is because I am still putting the deviceReady inside the click function which doesn't make sense at all. But i am struggling to figure out how to do this properly.

Can someone please advice on the above?

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

The main issue is this line of code (I think):

```
 document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
```

because of this line, the following code only runs onDeviceReady:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    var div = document.querySelector('.app');
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Scanning...'));
    div.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

    // scan for any BLE devices for 10 seconds
    ble.scan([], 10, app.onDeviceDiscovered);

    setTimeout(app.scanComplete, 10500);
}
```

Which makes the code die at that stage.

Comment: What if you just call app.initialize() from the click handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thers is no need to add and .on to document. You can keep everything the same, just change the listener from listening to the document to listen to the button your specifying

If your using jquery you can just change the event listener of your initialize function to this:

```
initialize: function() {
        $(".letmepairBtn").click(this.onDeviceReady.bind(this));
}
```

Or you can acheive the same thing with vanilla javascript, just change the eventlistener and the target:

```
initialize: function() {
    document.getElementsbyClassName('letmepairBtn')[0].addEventListener('click', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false)
}
```

Either way you can keep the same code as before, just call app.initialize at the end and wait for the click on the button.